# How to enable sensitive information in LB

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a Web application to which client logins.

While login, in inspect, i can see `authorization: Basic ABCDEFGHIJ....` under `Request Headers` which is base64 encoded which i can easily decode. How can i view the same in ALB lobs?

The traffic for this goes like client browser --> ALB --> etc..

Current Rule on ALB is, any traffic for https goes to `HTTPS:443` listener which matches if `HTTP Path Pattern is /*` and goes to its target group.

After checking the ALB logs, i cannot see such base64 encoded string. How can i add/enable `authorization: Basic ABC..` into the ALB logs so that i can decode and view it.

Regards

Tried checking existing logs but not seeing `authorization:`  header.

Comment: ALB won't log sensitive content like HTTP headers and body afaik.

Comment: Yes its not logging this info by default which is true but is there a way to log this?

Comment: You can see what ALB can log [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html). HTTP headers are not in that list. Your application would have to log the headers, e.g. to CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Hi Jarmod, Thanks for reply. Do you have doc link showing this (Your application would have to log the headers, e.g. to CloudWatch Logs)

Comment: I provided a link to what ALB does log. You can review that but I don't see HTTP headers listed (which doesn't surprise me tbh). That means some other component in your system would have to log the headers (ideally not those with sensitive information such as authorization tokens). Which component does the logging and where the logs are written to is largely your choice. There may also be third-party libraries that can help with this task.